# How to prevent windows on widget layer from taking focus?

Tags: compiz

I start Vim with a special role, and configure the Compiz widget layer plugin so that this Vim instance belongs to the widget layer. This gives me a scratchpad that I can show on any workspace with one keypress.

However when I alt-tab switch while the widget layer is hidden, the hidden Vim shows up in the switcher. To make this more irritating, if there are visible Vim instances on the workspace, they often don't get focus unless I wait for the switcher to expand to the application windows, and then select a specific window.

I would prefer the hidden Vim not to appear in the switcher, and not to take focus while it is hidden.

Is there a way to configure this?

Answer (score 1):

The answer turns out to be the Window Rules plugin. See http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Widget and http://wiki.compiz.org/WindowMatching#Winrules , specifically the *Skip taskbar* and *Skip pager* options.

Enter `widget=1` for these options to match windows on the widget layer.